# Find notes with accented characters when searching for the base character (like isearch with character folding)

Tags: search, org-roam

Emacs isearch has a "character folding" functionality which can be toggled with `M-s '` during isearch. When this is activated, the search can find something like "maçã" (apple in Portuguese) by searching with just "maca".

Is there a similar functionality when searching for notes with `org-roam-node-find`?

Currently I add a title alias to be able to find a note spelling it correctly, but this does not scale well and is also a problem if I later rename the note, since I'll have to remember to rename the alias as well.

Comment: As far as I know there is none, I think you can think of another solution to automatically add alias when creating new nodes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with org-roam, but in general `(search-forward-regexp (char-fold-to-regexp "maca") nil t)` should find maçã.